# Can existing results be returned when manually stopped in R

Tags: r, try-catch, return-value, exit

I'm using a function to process some data of 9000 items.
Sometimes the program will get stuck there after it has e.g., finished 6000 items.

In this case, I'll have to stop the program manually using the small red button in RStudio and have to restart a run from scratch.

I was wondering, if there are some ways that even I stop the program manually, it still can return existing results so that I don't have to restart from scratch.

May be something like `tryCatch` , but since manually stop is not actually an error, I have no idea how to do it with `tryCatch`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do would be to figure out why your program is getting stuck and fix the root cause.

If you discover that the cause for becoming "stuck" is outside of your control, **errors are your friend.** If you can detect the conditions that result in a problem, throw an error using `stop()`.

This can then be picked up elsewhere in your program using `tryCatch`. I've also found the [safely](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/safely.html) function of the `purrr` package invaluable for situations like these, because you can process a long list of error-prone files and decide how to handle the hiccups elegantly afterwards. I find it often results in neater code than `tryCatch`.

Some other strategies to consider:

**Interactive debugging**

If there's a way to detect that the program is stuck programmatically and you don't want to rework the code to handle errors, you can launch an interactive debugger with a call to `browser()`, e.g.

```
if (stuck) {
  browser()
}
```

You can then interact with the environment and manually resume execution.

**Storing progress**

It sounds like the function is processing items, and possibly producing output. If you can write the results of your calculations as you go, either to a file or somewhere in memory, then you may be able to add a condition in your code that skips items that have already been processed.

For example, using `file.exists()` and `saveRDS()` something like:

```
process_item <- function(item) {
    ... # some steps to produce a result

    # Then write the result to disk, using the hash of the input as the file name
    saveRDS(result, paste0(digest::digest(item), ".rds") 
    result  
}

for (i in seq_along(items)) {
  # skip items that have already been processed
  if (file.exists(digest::digest(items[[i]])) next
  process_item(items[[i]])
}
```

That way when you start the program again after it gets stuck, you won't waste time reprocessing items.

Comment: Thanks Callum, the thing is that I have no way to find out what's happening when it get stuck, maybe because the computer is running so much processes. But even after I turn others off, it still stuck there. The storing way could be one of the option.

Comment: It can indeed be difficult to track down what's going wrong when there isn't a crash or warning message being thrown!


Most of the concepts here won't be immediately useful since you don't have an error, but it could still help to take a look: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html

You might also benefit from making your code chattier by scattering some `cat` or `print` statements at key points, or if you have an area where you think something might be going wrong, use `browser` to launch the interactive debugger.